# Give border to image created in PHP

Tags: php, gd

How do I give a border to an image created using PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add image-border around an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589550/how-to-add-image-border-around-an-image)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function drawBorder(&$img, &$color, $thickness = 1) 
{
    $x1 = 0; 
    $y1 = 0; 
    $x2 = ImageSX($img) - 1; 
    $y2 = ImageSY($img) - 1; 

    for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++) 
    { 
        ImageRectangle($img, $x1++, $y1++, $x2--, $y2--, $color); 
    } 
}
```

Then the usage would just  to do.

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
drawBorder($img,$color, 255);
```

Comment: Error. You asked for $color but used  $color_black.

Comment: this is the right method to display images using PHP

header("content-type: image/jpeg");   
imagejpeg($image);

Comment: we would need to see your whole code to see if your sending the right haders etc.

Comment: i used your code and got only border on top, right and left but not on the bottom. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test this but I think it will do the trick.

```
function addBorder($image, $width, $height)
{
    $gd = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    for($i = 0; $i<$height; $i++)
    {
        // add left border
        imagesetpixel($image,0,$i, imagecolorallocate($gd, 0,0,0) );
        // add right border
        imagesetpixel($image,$width-1,$i, imagecolorallocate($gd, 0,0,0) );
    } 
    for($j = 0; $j<$width; $j++)
    {
        // add bottom border
        imagesetpixel($image,$j,0, imagecolorallocate($gd, 0,0,0) );
        // add top border
        imagesetpixel($image,$j,$height-1, imagecolorallocate($gd, 0,0,0) );
    }

    return $image;
}

$image = //your image
$width = //your iimage width
$height = //your image height


$image = addBorder($image, $width, $height);
```

Answer (score 1):

With ImageMagick:

[`bool Imagick::borderImage  (  mixed $bordercolor  ,  int $width  ,  int $height  )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-borderimage.php)

> Surrounds the image with a border of the color defined by the bordercolor ImagickPixel object.