# How to create thumbnail images with white 3px border using PHP?

Tags: php, image, gd

How to create thumbnail images with white 3px border using PHP?

Comment: Why not use CSS to add the border?

Comment: `<img style="border: 3px solid #000000;" src="..." />`

Comment: See the [various Thumbnail Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thumbnail+php) and [Give Border to Image Created in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006007/give-border-to-image-created-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't actually tried this but I think something like this might work

```
<?php

/*
* Function to create a border around an image
*/
function drawBorder($image_name, $r = 0, $g = 0, $b = 0, $thickness = 1)
{
  $image = ImageCreateFromJPEG($image_name);
  $color = ImageColorAllocate($img, $r, $g, $b);

  $x1 = 0;
  $y1 = 0;
  $x2 = ImageSX($image) - 1;
  $y2 = ImageSY($image) - 1;

  for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++)
  {
    ImageRectangle($image, $x1++, $y1++, $x2--, $y2--, $color);
  }

  return $image;
}

?>
```

Then run something like

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
ImageJPEG(drawBorder("images/foo.jpg", 128, 128, 0, 3));
?>
```

Comment: Ahhh... And if you actually wanted WHITE borders (missed that) you just pass 255, 255, 255 as the rgb values.
WOuld also probably be nice to have a switch statement to actually check the type of image and then using the appropriate ImageCreateFrom* function.

Answer (score 0):

create a jpg (or gif/png) which is 6px heigher and 6px widther than the given thumbnail. take the desired border color as background color. then copy your thumbnail in it with startingpos 3px, 3px ;-)

best practice using imagick library

Answer (score 0):

```
function addBorderpng($add){
    $border=5; 
    $im=imagecreatefrompng($add);
    $width=imagesx($im);
    $height=imagesy($im);       
    $img_adj_width=$width+(2*$border);
    $img_adj_height=$height+(2*$border);
    $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($img_adj_width,$img_adj_height);     

    $border_color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($newimage,0,0,$img_adj_width,
```

$img_adj_height,$border_color);

```
    imagecopyresized($newimage,$im,$border,$border,0,0,
```

$width,$height,$width,$height);
        imagepng($newimage,$add,9); 
        chmod("$add",0666);

```
}
```